# @import SCSS files not recognized by compiler?

Tags: sass, blazor, web-compiler

It won't compile it says:

> Undefined variable: "$blue-logo-color."

In variables.scss I have:

```
$blue-logo-color: #3cabf5;
```

and in site.scss I have:

```
@import "variables.scss"

.blue-logo-color {
    color: $blue-logo-color;
}

.blue-logo-background-color {
    background-color: $blue-logo-color;
}
```

How can I make the WebCompiler include global scss/css files for the compiler? It also doesn't seem to recognize global includes from _Hosts.cshtml.

Comment: you need a semicolon at the end of the import statement

Comment: You are right, that fixed it.

Comment: I should probably add it as an answer

Comment: Why did you tag Less when it's a Sass question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCSS import statements require a semicolon

```
@import "variables.scss";
```

Comment: How to import an scss file into scoped scss files? The compiler doesn't recognize the global includes and @ import is not allowed in a scoped file like for example: Index.razor.scss can't use @ import.

Comment: I've got imports in scoped files (*page.razor.scss) with no problems using relative paths eg: @import '../SCSS/Variables.scss';

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio solved the scoped import.